# how to pass 0 days when enddate is empty or null i nsql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

hi firends hi small doubt in sql server please tell me how to solve this 
issue.
table :emp

```
   fromdate and enddate both columns datatype varchar.

  id| fromdate     |   Enddate
   1|   2014-03-20 |   2014-03-25
   2|  2014-03-15  |  
   3|   2014-02-24 |  2014-02-27
   4|  2014-03-10  | 
   5|  2014-02-13  |
   6|  2014-03-01  | 2014-03-10
```

based on this i want output like below

```
id | Noofdays
  1  |  5
  2  |  0
  3  |  3
  4  |  0
  5   | 0
  6   | 9
```

here i need to get noof days between from and endate .
when enddate is empty or null then we treated as noof days is  0 days.
and i tried like below

```
select 
datediff(day,fromdate,(CASE WHEN coalesce(ltrim(rtrim([nddate])),'') = '' THEN '0' ELSE ltrim(rtrim([emrenddate])) END)
) from  emp
```

but its  showing error please  tell me how to solve issue in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, 
case
 when (enddate is null) or (enddate = '') then 0
 else datediff(day, cast(ltrim(rtrim(fromdate)) as datetime),  cast(ltrim(rtrim(enddate)) as datetime))
end as NoOfDays
from yourtable
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query change "nddate" to Fromdate and  emrenddate to EndDate. It will show NULL instead of 0. If you want 0 instead of NULL use query provided by shree.pat18